# Почему не обновляется информация в базе?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Есть форма, которая отправляет данные в обработчик:

```
<p class="style10">Редактирование главной страницы </p>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="3.php">

  <p class="style9"><strong>Тэг &quot;мета кейвордс&quot;: </strong></p>
  <p class="style9">
    <label>
    <input type="text" name="meta_k" style="width: 400px; padding: 5px;" value="<? echo $myrow["meta_k"] ?>">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p class="style9"><strong>Тэг &quot;мета дескрипшинс&quot;:</strong></p>
  <p class="style9">
    <label>
    <input type="text" name="meta_d"  style="width: 400px; padding: 5px;" value="<? echo $myrow["meta_d"] ?>">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p class="style9"><strong>Тэг &quot;тайтл&quot;: </strong></p>
  <p class="style9">
    <label>
    <input type="text" name="tag_title"  style="width: 400px; padding: 5px;" value="<? echo $myrow["tag_title"] ?>">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p class="style9"><strong>Заголовок страницы:</strong></p>
  <p class="style9">
    <label>
    <input type="text" name="title"  style="width: 400px; padding: 5px;" value="<? echo $myrow["title"] ?>">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p class="style9"><strong>Текст страницы: </strong></p>
  <p class="style9">
    <label>
    <textarea name="text"  style="width: 400px; padding: 5px; height: 200px;"><? echo $myrow["text"] ?></textarea>
    </label>
  </p>

      <input name="sub" type="submit">

      </form>
```

Далее информация обновляется в базе:

```
    if (isset($_POST['title']))      {$title = $_POST['title']; if ($title == '') {unset($title);}}
if (isset($_POST['text']))      {$text = $_POST['text']; if ($text == '') {unset($text);}}
if (isset($_POST['meta_d']))      {$meta_d = $_POST['meta_d']; if ($meta_d == '') {unset($meta_d);}}
if (isset($_POST['meta_k']))      {$meta_k = $_POST['meta_k']; if ($meta_k == '') {unset($meta_k);}}
if (isset($_POST['tag_title']))      {$tag_title = $_POST['tag_title']; if ($tag_title == '') {unset($tag_title);}}

if (isset($title))
{
/* Здесь пишем что можно заносить информацию в базу */
$result2 = mysql_query ("UPDATE settings SET title='$title', tag_title='$tag_title', meta_d='$meta_d', meta_k='$meta_k', text='$text' WHERE page='how'");

if ($result2 == 'true') {echo "1";}
else {echo "2";}

}        
else

{
echo "3";
}
```

Почему-то, если в текстовое поле (переменная `$text`) вбивать короткий текст, то информация успешно обновляется. Но если вбить например:

```
<p>You surf the Pre-Dating.com site to learn all about it. Each city page has a list of events and a way for you to be notified of future ones. See the Scheduled Events page for a list of all Pre-Dating cities.</p>
<p>You register for an event on our Web site, by fax or by phone (to ensure equal numbers of men and women, you MUST pre-register, there are no on-site registrations!). If you don't see an event that matches your preferences, please join the Event Notification List. </p>
<p>Within seconds after you register, we email you all the event details including directions. If you don't get this email contact us.</p>
<p>You show up a few minutes EARLY for the event, get your name tag and Match Sheet scorecard.</p>
<p>You meet 6 to 12 (and sometimes more) other single professionals in less than 2 hours (via a series of 6-minute &quot;Pre-Dates&quot;). We facilitate the whole thing so you are guaranteed to meet everyone there in a safe and fun way. To maximize your experience, we usually hold events in private or semi-private areas at an upscale venue. Many events include free appetizers and/or drink specials.</p>
<p>On your Match Sheet, you decide who you'd like to know better and they do the same. At the end of the event, you enter your Match Sheet selections on our Web site at Pre-Dating.com.</p>
<p>Your initial party results are received within 24 hours! Pre-Dating then emails each guest a list of participants who would like to hear from them again! Odds are you'll have one or more matches (more than two-thirds of Pre-Daters match at least one person).</p>
<p>After that, it's up to you! Since you've had a Pre-Date, your chances of making a more lasting connection are vastly increased.<br>
</p>
<p>Have more questions? Read our Frequently Asked Questions page, email your local coordinator or click the button below to chat live with Pre-Dating Customer Service.</p>
<p>Not sure? Join the notification list for your area to be notified of future events in your area that match your interest preferences.</p>
<p>Read Attendee Reviews of Pre-Dating Events</p>
```

то информация не обновляется в базе. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ух! Узнаю школу Попова )) Ужас, летящий на крыльях ночи :D У меня сон, как рукой сняло ))

Поле "text" в БД какой тип имеет? У меня ощущение, что не тип **text**, а **varchar**, например. И пректращайте мозг калечить! Курсы Попова в мусорку, хорошую книгу - в руки.
В сети даже есть [курс "реабилитации"](http://irbis-team.com/15/10/1?PHPSESSID=dbdac8ea77ad4b0c7c8d72078ec0de43), после видеоуроков Жени.

А этот кусочек кода, я распечатаю и на стену в рамочку ;)

```
if ($result2 == 'true') {echo "1";}
else {echo "2";}

}        
else

{
echo "3";
}
```

P.S. Вы тут ни при чём. Вы просто одна из жертв, которая попалась на крючок.

Comment: за всю мою карьеру это наверно самый ужасный код который я видел

Comment: Нет. Тип text, а не варчар. До, по Попова курсу учусь.

Comment: @Pavlik290592, если с типом поля все нормально, то это уже хорошо. Тот текст, который который вы показали, кишит апострофами/одинарными кавычками. Я уверен, что строки вы не обрабатывали перед апдейтом, а это надо **обязательно делать** в любом случае. Поэтому сделайте так для всех переменных, значения которых будут вносится в БД:

    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);

Comment: А что с его курсами не так? Я просто хочу у него по ЯваСкрипт купить.

Comment: @Pavlik290592, в своем ответе я вам дал ссылочку. Почитайте все шесть "шагов", там не так много. В этих статейках, на примере уроков Попова, показывается - "**как делать НЕ надо**". В комментариях на ХэшКоде дается всего 600 символов и поверьте, что если я начну перечислять все ошибки вашего кода, то мне их точно не хватит.